# MySQL nested count statement

Tags: mysql

imagine that I have 2 tables and I would like to calculate the best selling artists:

- music (id, title, barcode)
- artists (barcode, artist)

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(m.barcode) AS sells, m.barcode, artist
  FROM music m
  LEFT JOIN artists a
  ON m.barcode = a.barcode
  GROUP BY m.barcode ORDER BY sells DESC
  ```

This query returns e.g.:

```
  sells    | barcode |   artist
 ---------------------------------
   1000        123       jdoe
    500        223       kloe
    100        321       jdoe
```

How can I calculate that jdoe complexively sold 1100 music?

Thanks in advance for any hint

Comment: Erm, group by artist?

Comment: If you don't care about individual barcodes, why are you selecting and grouping them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `group by` from `barcode` to `artist` (and remove `barcode` from the `select` statement):

```
SELECT COUNT(m.barcode) AS sells, artist
FROM music m LEFT JOIN
     artists a
     ON m.barcode = a.barcode
GROUP BY artist
ORDER BY sells DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(m.barcode) AS popular, m.barcode, a.artist, SUM(a.sell) 
FROM `music` AS m 
LEFT JOIN `artists` AS a 
ON (m.barcode = a.barcode)
WHERE a.artist = 'jdoe'
GROUP BY m.barcode 
ORDER BY `popular` DESC
```